# rexster-server(rexster-server-2.5.0) error for titan 0.5.0

Tags: graph-databases, titan

Run TexSter server 2.5.0 for Titan using BDB and Lucene ,get Following error:
    C:\software\nosql\rexster\rexster-server-2.5.0\rexster-server-2.5.0>bin\rexster.bat -s -c config\rexster.xml
    [INFO] Application - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
    [INFO] RexsterProperties - Using [C:\software\nosql\rexster\rexster-server-2.5.0\rexster-server-2.5.0\config\rexster.xml] as configuration source.
    [INFO] Application - Rexster is watching [C:\software\nosql\rexster\rexster-server-2.5.0\rexster-server-2.5.0\config\rexster.xml] for change.
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/software/nosql/rexster/rexster-server-2.5.0/rexster-server-2.5.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/Sta
    ticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/software/nosql/rexster/rexster-server-2.5.0/rexster-server-2.5.0/ext/titan/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/im
    pl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    [INFO] Reflections - Reflections took 8948 ms to scan 417 urls, producing 143 keys and 11163 values
    [INFO] GraphDatabaseConfiguration - Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8016611484-IBM-RR0A746AMG41
    [INFO] Backend - Configuring index [search]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:42)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:425)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:412)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.(Backend.java:131)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1604)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.(StandardTitanGraph.java:107)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:92)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:71)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance(TitanGraphConfiguration.java:33)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:54)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRexsterApplication.java:99)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.(XmlRexsterApplication.java:47)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.(Application.java:97)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)

Answer (score 1):

delete lucene-core-3.6.2 on \rexster-server-2.5.0\lib\